# Laravel Pagination / Count - Not Accurate AFTER Filters Applied

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5, eloquent

When I retrieve the count for my results via laravel's paginator ($var->total() function) OR adding on ->count() to my DB query, it returns the incorrect count. Even when there is ZERO items on the page after a filter is applied, it still shows the incorrect number. This number stays the same, it doesn't change - it's the total # of rows in my parent model. However, again - it shouldn't show the total # of rows in my parent model - it should show the rows that are available after a filter is applied.

Filtered Query in Question:

```
$orders = list_formstack::with(['order' => function($query) use ($checktv, $dstart, $dend, $thestatus, $pharmacy, $searchid, $searchsubid, $searchrefill, $searchgrams, $filterrep) {
                $query->whereNotNull('subid');
                if($checktv == "No") {
                    $query->whereNull('intake');    
                }
                elseif($checktv == "Yes") {
                    $query->whereNotNull('intake'); 
                }
                if($dstart && $dend)
                    $query->whereBetween('orders.created_at', [$dstart, $dend]);
                if($thestatus)
                    $query->where('orders.status', $thestatus);
                if($pharmacy)
                    $query->where('pharmacy', $pharmacy);
                if($searchid)
                    $query->where('orders.id', $searchid);
                if($searchsubid)
                    $query->where('orders.subid', $searchsubid);
                if($searchrefill)
                    $query->where('refill', $searchrefill);
                if($searchgrams)
                    $query->where('grams', $searchgrams);
                if($filterrep)
                    $query->where('salesrep', $filterrep);
            }])->where(function($query) use ($prodgroup, $state, $search, $columns, $searchpatient, $searchcarrier) {
                if($state)
                    $query->where('state', $state);
                if($searchpatient)
                    $query->where('first', 'like', $searchpatient)->orWhere('last', $searchpatient)->orWhere('phone', $searchpatient);
                if($searchcarrier)
                    $query->where('insurancecarrier', 'like', $searchcarrier);
            })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(50);
```

Parent Model:

```
class list_formstack extends Model
{
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'formstack';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['parentid','first','last','state','insurancecarrier'];

/**
 * Get the form for an order
 */
public function order()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\list_orders', 'formid', 'id')->groupBy('id');
}
}
```

Child / Relationship Model:

```
class list_orders extends Model
{
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'orders';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['id','status','subid','formid','salesrep','billedamt','copayamt','completed','refillcount','gramsleft','billedamt','copayamt','salesrep','intake','created_at'];

public function formstack()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\list_formstack', 'orderid');
}
}
```

So as you can see in my Eloquent query, I filter out results based on whether a user chooses that filter or not. So if I filter out "thestatus" to one specific status, it shows the correct results for only that status HOWEVER the count DOES NOT change.

I even tried to throw the results into a collection:

```
$count = collect($orders);
$count->count();
```

No luck - same incorrect number.

Any insight on this? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I should note that using Laravel's Query Builder (NO Eloquent ORM Models) results in the pagination count working correctly.

Parent Model DB Table
[Parent Model Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkN2a.png)
Child Model DB Table
[Child Model Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCi5z.png)

Comment: Can you show your table structure here. And one more thing do not use class name in lowercase. Class name must be in Capitalize manner. So `list_orders` would become `ListOrders`. Follow the conventions properly

Comment: @AlankarMore I've added screenshots of tables structure.

Comment: Having the same issue. How did you solve this?